# Can I get a shortcut to the Downloaded Files folder?

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, downloading

When an file or app downloads from a browser (as opposed to installing directly), the downloads open up.

Otherwise, I can't seem to navigate in there.

Is there a way, on a stock, un-rooted Android, to navigate to the download list?

Update: browsing through "File Manager", I see I've been staring at `/sdcard/download` -- how does this view "normally" open after a file download?

I'm on an HTC Incredible, Froyo 2.2, but I'd expect this to be similar for most, no?

Comment: Are you talking about downloads in the Market, or files downloaded from the internet (ie. in the browser)?

Comment: Yes, I second that question.  Didn't even think of reading it that way until I saw keightjgrant's comment.

Comment: updated to clarify, FIVE YEARS LATER, that it is browser downloads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually your apps are downloaded using your browser. For accessing them you open your browser, press menu > more > downloads.

Comment: I use Dolphin as the browswer, and with there it is simply `menu >> downloads` -- and that's the screen I was seeing before. Sheesh. Without title-bars, there's no context for what I'm staring at. I never know if I'm looking at an application screen, or an OS screen. Well, sometimes.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to add a shortcut on your home screen to your Downloads folder or any other folder for that matter get [ASTRO File Manager (free)](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.metago.astro).  The app is pretty useful on it's own, but it also adds the option to create a shortcut directly to any folder on the homescreen.  To do this, simply long click on the homescreen, choose "Shortcuts", then choose "ASTRO" then choose the particular folder you want a shortcut to.

I had ASTRO for a while before I realized I could do this because the option is deceiving.  At first look I thought it would create a shortcut to the app, not to a specific folder like it does.

**Edit:** After reading Keith's comment I realized you are probably talking about market downloads.  In that case do what [Al Everett said](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1235/can-i-get-a-shortcut-to-the-downloads/1243#1243).

Comment: Very helpful to me Matt, as I couldn't find the question "how do I create a folder shortcut on Home screen" on here.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. Open up the "Market" app, open the menu, and choose "Downloads".

Answer (score 2):

Go to your home screen, long press on any area then choose to add "**Shortcut**" => "**Activities**". Then you'll see a long expandable list. You need to find here "**Downloads**". Click on it to expand it and then choose second entry - "**.DownloadList**"

(Tested on Android 4.4.2 - Samsung Galaxy S5 Mini)

Answer (score 1):

Just open the marketplace and under menu, you'll find Downloads. 
Another suggestion, if there are apps you use a lot you can create a shortcut to your homescreen by long pressing on an area of the homescreen where there is room for an icon, select Shortcuts > Applications and pick anything to save to your homescreen. I made a few folders on my homescreen of apps, for example one is called Games, one is called Utilities. Then I filled them with the apps I use most. Long press on the homescreen, select Folders > New Folder, keep it open and press on the application launcher, long press on anything you want to save into your folder and it will save there.

Answer (score 0):

With Ice Cream Sandwich, I have a new app in my app drawer called "Downloads" which brings me to a list of recently downloaded files.

Obviously you can drop this as a shortcut on your home screen.

[image: Downloads icon]